# Probabilistic method and graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, probabilistic-method, extremal-graph-theory

1. Let $G$ be a simple graph with maximum degree $9$ and $e$ edges. Show that we can partition the set of vertices into two sets such that the number of edges between two set is at least $\frac{5}{9}e$.
2. Show that there is a graph on $n$ vertices with at least $O(n^{4/3})$ edges and without any square.

Comment: What is a square $K_4$ or $C_4$?

Comment: What is a source of this problem(s)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution to problem 2:

We construct a random graph on $n$ vertices by adding each edge with probability $p$, independently and uniformly.  Thus, the expected number of edges is $p\binom{n}{2}$.  For every collection $S$ of four vertices, we have that the probability they form a square is $p^4$.  For every square that is formed, we remove one edge, thereby removing the square from the graph.  Thus, the expected number of edges is greater than or equal to $$ p \binom{n}{2} - 3 p^4 \binom{n}{4}.$$  Taking $p = n^{-2/3}$ gives that this expectation is $O(n^{4/3})$, implying there is a graph with no squares having at least $O(n^{4/3})$ edges.

Comment: Hmm, is it realy $p^4$? Say the set of vertices is $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and set of edges  $1-2-3-1$ and $1-4$. Is that a square?

Comment: I believe it should be $3p^4\binom{n}{4}$ instead of $p^4\binom{n}{4}$ here (since for any $4$ vertices there are $3$ possible $4$-cycles that span them).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added the factor of $3$ now, which thankfully does not change the answer.

Answer (score 4):

For Problem 1: Let $\sigma$ be an ordering of the vertices of $G$ (i.e. a permutation of the $n$ vertices of $G$).  Call a vertex $v$ **good** if there are an odd number of neighbors of $v$ appearing before $v$ in $\sigma$.

**Claim 1:** Let $v$ be a vertex of degree $d(v)$.  If $d(v)$ is odd, then $v$ is good for exactly half of all possible orderings.  If $d(v)$ is even, then $v$ is good for a $\frac{d(v)}{2d(v)+2}$ fraction of all possible orderings.

*Proof:* The goodness of $v$ depends only on the relative ordering of $v$ and its $d(v)$ neighbors, so it suffices to consider permutations only of those $d(v)+1$ vertices.    Let $\tau \in S_{d(v)}$ be the relative permutation of the neighbors.  For each $\tau$, there are $d(v)+1$ places we can insert $v$ in this ordering to create a permutation of $d(v)+1$ vertices, all of which are equally likely.  The vertex $v$ is good if we insert $v$ after $1, 3, 5, \dots$ vertices.  This means there's $(d(v)+1)/2$ good places to insert $v$ if $d(v)$ is odd, and $d(v)/2$ good places if $d(v)$ is even.

**Claim 2:** There is a choice of $\sigma$ such that there are at least $$\frac{n}{2} - \sum_{v \textrm{ with }\atop d(v) \textrm{ even}} \frac{1}{2d(v)+2}$$ good vertices.

*Proof:* Consider a randomly chosen $\sigma$.  The expected number of good vertices is equal to the sum over all $v$ of the probability that $v$ is good.   We found this probability in Claim $1$, and the formula here corresponds to adding all that up.

**Claim 3:** There is a partition of the vertices with at least 
$$\frac{e}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{n}{2} - \sum_{v \textrm{ with }\atop d(v) \textrm{ even}} \frac{1}{2d(v)+2}\right)$$
edges crossing between the two halves.

*Proof:* Fix a $\sigma=(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n)$ satisfying the conclusion of Claim $2$.  We now partition the vertices of $\sigma$ in order, putting each $v_j$ on whichever side creates more crossing edges between $v_j$ and $\{v_1, \dots, v_{j-1}\}$.  Let $a_j$ be the number of edges between $v_j$ and earlier vertices.  There will always be a choice of sides which creates at least $\lceil \frac{a_j}{2} \rceil$
crossing edges.  This is equal to at least $\frac{a_j}{2}$, but we get an extra half edge every time $v$ is good.  These additional half edges correspond to the second term in the claim.

**Claim 4:** For any $G$ with maximum degree $9$, there is a partition with at least $\frac{5e}{9}$ edges.

*Proof:* Think of the expression in claim $3$ as 
$$\frac{e}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \sum_v f(v),$$
where 
$$f(v) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & \textrm{ if } d(v) \textrm{ is odd } \\ 1- \frac{1}{d(v)+1} & \textrm{ if } d(v) \textrm{ is even } \end{array}\right.$$
It can be checked by direct calculation that $f(v) \geq \frac{1}{9} d(v)$ whenever $d(v) \leq 9$ (equality holding both for $d(v)=8, f(v)=\frac{8}{9}$ and $d=9, f(v)=1$).  So the number of crossing edges is at least 
$$\frac{e}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \sum_v \frac{1}{9} d(v) = \frac{e}{2} + \frac{1}{18} \left(\frac{1}{2} \sum_v d(v) \right) = \frac{e}{2} + \frac{1}{18} e = \frac{5e}{9}.$$

Comment: That should have been $d(v) \leq 9$

Comment: As a side note: The Greedy algorithm described in Claim 3 has been studied a fair amount.  Even when there's no good edges, it will always achieve at least $\frac{e}{2}$ edges crossing.  Without further information (e.g. the Max-degree $9$) condition, this is about the best possible (consider for example a complete graph -- no crossing beats $\frac{e}{2}$).  So instead the question shifts to whether the partition you get from the algorithm is anywhere close to the optimal partition.  A few results along these lines:

Comment: Poloczek and Schnitger ("Randomized Variants of Johnson's Algorithm for MAX-SAT") showed that there is some ordering $\sigma$ for which the partition generated by the Claim 3 procedure is the best among any partition.  Mathieu and Schudy ("Yet another Algorithm for Dense Max Cut: Go Greedy") showed that if the graph is dense ($cn^2$ edges) and $n$ is large, choosing a random $\sigma$ gives you a nearly optimal partition...

Comment: Conversely, I showed with Shapira and Tetali ("On Randomizing Two Derandomized Greedy Algorithms") that there are (non-dense) graphs where the Claim $3$ algorithm usually creates $\approx \frac{e}{2}$ crossing edges even though the actual best partition has every edge in the graph crossing (because the graph is bipartite).  In general, the problem of actually finding the best partition (the so-called "Max Cut" problem) is believed to be computationally hard for large graphs.

Comment: Any way the alteration here does not apply like in 2. question? I don't know much about the probability it is just a naive question.

Comment: I think alteration may be at least able to get you $\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon$ for some positive $\epsilon$, but I'm not sure if it'll get you all the way up to $\frac{5}{9}$.  The idea would be to take a random assignment (which on average cuts half the edges), then look for vertices that have more neighbors in their own set than the opposite set (so moving them increases the number of cut vertices).  On average this will be a positive fraction of vertices.  The difficulty is keeping track of second order effects from edges connecting two vertices that are both moved.

Comment: Hello again, I don't know if you saw this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382140/say-e-1-e-n-subset-1-2-k-k-each-e-i-4-and-each-j-in-k-appear?noredirect=1#comment6960747_3382140 Can you help me about it?

Comment: Or equivalent one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358882/domination-problem-with-sets/3031850#3031850

Answer (score 0):

*For path I.*

Consider complete graph that has $|E(G)|=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ number of edges, an example about simple graphs. Show first that $K_n$ satisfy the condition and prove inductively on each spanning subgraph of $K_n$ such as $K_k -h$ where $h$ is an edge satisfy the condition. Your goal is to show that the condition is satisfied with every simple subgraph.

I haven't proved this but the below shows the idea. You may need to partition again after the removal to satisfy the condition again.

**Example**

Consider $K_{9}$ with vertex sets $S$ and $H$: you start with all vertices in $S$. Move one vertex to $H$ so nice edges between $S$ and $H$. Move second vertex to $H$ so $(9-1)+8=16$ vertex between $S$ and $H$. You can increase the number of edges between $S$ and $H$ until 4 vertices in $S$ and $5$ in $H$. So $9+8+7+6 \geq 4*5=20$ vertices between $S$ and $H$ is the maximum edge count. $4+3+2+1=10$ edges in $H$ and $3+2+1=6$ edges in $S$. And $|E(K_9)|=36 =20+10+6$. Notice that $5/9\cdot |E(G)|=5/9\cdot 36=20$ so the condition is satisfied.

Now remove an edge $h$ between the sets $S$ and $H$ so the graph $G-h$ has 35 edges so $5/9\cdot 35=19.4444....> 19$ so the condition is not satisfied. This means the graph $K_9-h$ must be partioned again until again 20 edges between $S$ and $H$. In next removal, $34\cdot 5/9>19$ so only 19 edges now required between $S$ and $H$.