# Domination problem with sets

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, discrete-optimization, extremal-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

> Let $M$ be a non-empty and finite set, $S_1,...,S_k$ subsets
>   of $M$, satisfying:
>
> (1) $|S_i|\leq 3,i=1,2,...,k$
>
> (2) Any element of $M$ is an element of at least $4$ sets among
>   $S_1,....,S_k$.
>
> Show that one can select $[\frac{3k}{7}] $ sets from $S_1,...,S_k$
>   such that their union is $M$.

---

*Partial solution:* I can find a family of ${13\over 25}k$ such sets that no element in $M$ is in more then 3 set from that family. Thus we have a family of the size ${13\over 25}k$ instead of ${4\over 7}k$.

Say $|M| =n$.

Let' s take any set independently with a probability $p$. Let's mark with $X$ a number of a chosen sets and with $Y$ a number of elements that are ''bad''
i.e. elements which are in at least 4 sets among a chosen sets. Note that $4n\leq 3k$. Then we have $$E(X-Y)=E(X)-E(Y) \geq  kp-np^4 \geq kp (1-3p^3/4)$$Since a function $x \mapsto  x(1-3x^3/4)$ achives a maximum at $x=\sqrt[3]{1/3}$ we have $E(X-Y)\geq {\sqrt[3]{9}\over 4}k> {13\over 25}k$.

So with the method of alteration we find constant ${\sqrt[3]{9}\over 4}$ which is about $0,051$ worse then ${4\over 7}$.

---

The question is cross-posted to [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317076/domination-problem-with-sets)

---

***For a full solution with probabilistic method I'm offering  $\color{red}{500}$ points of bounty at any time.***

Comment: Interesting. Also, I apologize for my earlier comment; I didn't understand til right now that you were throwing out sets instead of keeping them. I'm doubtful that a purely probabilistic proof of this fact exists, but I'll think about it

Comment: @aqua why do you keep talking about $\frac{4}{7}$, instead of $\frac{3}{7}$, in your probabilistic partial solution? And what is $X$?

Comment: I was looking how many sets can we delete so that union of the rest is still set M. @mathworker21

Comment: @Aqua I feel like one day you will try to solve global poverty with the probabilistic method :). I will think about this problem

Answer (score 2):

An algorithmic solution:

Clearly we can assume that each element in $M$ appears in exactly $4$ subsets. Let $|M| =n$.

**Stage 1.** Take maximal subfamily $\mathcal{A} \subseteq
\{S_1,....,S_k\} =:\mathcal{S} $ such that:

$\bullet$ every member of that family $\mathcal{A}$ has 3 elements;

$\bullet$ all sets in $\mathcal{A}$ are pairwise disjunct.

Let $|\mathcal{A}| =a$ and let $A= \cup _{X\in \mathcal{A}} X$.
Then $|A|=3a$. Now, since each $a\in A$ appears exactly $4$ times
it must appear exactly $3$ times in sets not in $\mathcal{A}$. So by double counting between $M$ and $\mathcal{S}\setminus \mathcal{A}$ we have (elements in $A$ have a degree $3$ and other $4$) $$ 3\cdot 3a +4(n-3a)\leq 3\cdot (k-a)\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;4n \leq 3k\;\;\;...(1)$$

Let us now erase all the elements in $M$ which appears in $A$ and let this new set be $M_1$, so $M_1 = M\setminus A$ (so $|M_1| = n-3a$) and do the same thing in remaining sets in $\mathcal{S}\setminus \mathcal{A}$ and we get new family of sets $\mathcal{S}_1$.

Notice that each element in $M_1$ appears still $4$ times in sets from $\mathcal{S}_1$ and that each set in $\mathcal{S}_1$ has at most $2$ elements. (Why? If some of it, say $X$, has $3$ elements, that means that no element in $X$ was erased, so no element in $X$ is in $A$. But then we could put $X$ in $\mathcal{A}$ and we would get bigger family than $\mathcal{A}$ which is already maximal.) Also, let $k_1=|\mathcal{S}_1|$

**Stage 2.** Now take a maximal subfamily $\mathcal{B} \subseteq
\mathcal{S}_1 $ such that:

$\bullet$   every member of that family $\mathcal{B}$ has 2 elements;

$\bullet$    all sets in $\mathcal{B}$ are pairwise disjunct.

Let $|\mathcal{B}| =b$ and let $B= \cup _{X \in \mathcal{B}} X$.
Then $|B|=2b$. Now, since each $b\in B$ appears exactly $4$ times
it must appear exactly $3$ times in sets not in $\mathcal{B}$. So by double counting between $M_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_1\setminus \mathcal{B}$ we have (elements in $B$ have a degree $3$ and other $4$) $$ 3\cdot 2b +4(n-3a-2b)\leq 2\cdot (k_1-b)\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;2n \leq k+5a\;\;\;...(2)$$

Let us now erase all the elements in $M_1$ which appears in $B$ and let this new set be $M_2$, so $M_2 = M_1\setminus B$ (so $|M_2| =n-3a-2b$) and do the same thing in remaining sets in $\mathcal{S}_1\setminus \mathcal{B}$ and we get new family of sets $\mathcal{S}_2$.

Notice that each element in $M_2$ appears still 4 times in sets from $\mathcal{S}_2$ and that each set in $\mathcal{S}_2$ has at most 1 elements. (Why? If some of it, say $X$, has 2 elements, that means that no element in $X$ was erased, so no element in $X$ is in $B$. But then we could put $X$ in $\mathcal{B}$ and we would get bigger family than $\mathcal{B}$ which is already maximal.) Also, let $k_2=|\mathcal{S}_2|$.

**Final stage.** Now take a maximal subfamily $\mathcal{C} \subseteq
\mathcal{S}_2 $ such that:

$\bullet$ every member of that family $\mathcal{C}$ has 1 element;

$\bullet$ all sets in $\mathcal{C}$ are pairwise disjunct.

Let $|\mathcal{C}| =c$ and let $C= \cup _{X \in \mathcal{C}} X$.
Then $|C|=c$. Now, since each $c\in C$ appears exactly 4 times
it must appear exactly 3 times in sets not in $\mathcal{C}$. So by double counting between $M_2$ and $\mathcal{S}_2\setminus \mathcal{C}$ we have (elements in $C$ have a degree $3$ and other $4$) $$ 3\cdot c +4(n-3a-2b-c)\leq 1\cdot (k_2-c)\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;4n \leq k+11a+7b\;\;\;...(3)$$

Clearly $C=M_2$ so we are finish with the process, that is $c+2b+3a = |M| =n$. All we have to check if resurrected sets (that is, we refile all the sets with erased elements) satisfies $$a+b+c\leq {3\over 7}k\;\;\;\; {\bf ?}$$

Using (1) and $3a+2b+c=n$ we get:
$$ 12a+8b+4c\leq 3k$$
Using (2) and $3a+2b+c=n$ we get:
$$ a+4b+2c\leq k$$
Using (3) and $3a+2b+c=n$ we get:
$$ 2a+2b+8c\leq 2k$$
If we add these three inequalites we get
So $$ 14(a+b+c)<15a+14b+14c\leq 6k$$ and thus a conclusion.