# Say $E_1,...E_n\subset\{1,2,...,k\}= K$, each $|E_i|=4$ and each $j\in K$ appear in at most $3$ sets $E_i$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization, extremal-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

> Say $E_1,...E_n\subset\{1,2,...,k\}= K$, each $|E_i|=4$ and each $j\in K$ appear in at most $3$ sets $E_i$. We choose from each $E_i$ one number. Prove that we can do that so that a set of all choosen numbers has not more than ${3k\over 7}$ members.

---

This was my try but the bound I get is not good and also I'm not even sure if it is correct.

We choose at random from each $E_i$ independently a number with a probability $p=1/4$ (so we can chose the same number more then once) and name this number $c_i$. Let $M$ be a set of choosen numbers and let $X=|M|$. If $X_i$ is indicator random variable for a number $i\in K$ then $$E(X) = E(X_1)+...+E(X_k)$$

Say $i$ is in a sets $E_1,...E_{d_i}$, where $d_i\leq 3$, then  \begin{eqnarray}E(X_i) &=& P(X_i=1) \\
&=& P(\{i=c_1\}\cup ...\cup \{i=c_{d_i}\})\\
&=&1-P(\{i\ne c_1\}\cap ...\cap \{i\ne c_{d_i}\})\\
&=&1-P(i\ne c_1)\dots P(i\ne c_{d_i})\\
&=&1-\Big({3\over 4}\Big)^{d_i}\\
\end{eqnarray}

So we have $$E(X)= k-\sum _{i=1}^k\Big({3\over 4}\Big)^{d_i}\leq k-k\Big({3\over 4}\Big)^3$$

So $E(X) \leq {37k\over 64}$ which is not good enough.

---

Anyone solve this one with **a probabilistic** method gets bounty **500pt**.

Comment: Isn't this extremely similar to, or maybe even equivalent to, [one of your older questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358882/domination-problem-with-sets)?  Esp. if you look at both from the viewpoint of a $0/1$-incidence matrix...?

Comment: @antkam Yeah, but I offered new dress and new "solution". Do you have some comment on a solution?

Comment: haha, sorry, i actually did think about your old problem for a while - the 500 bounty was very tempting!  but i couldnt solve it.  BTW i think your new solution is valid (although not tight enough for your requirement).

Comment: @antkam 500 goes here also

Comment: LOL i am not accusing you of dressing this up to avoid paying the 500!  :D  i still have no solution...  but i will give this another go.

Comment: @Aqua is it 600 or 500 reputation for answering within the next 7 days?

Comment: @mathworker21 I'll give you 1000 if you help me solve it. Have you perhaps read  my answer down? Is it correct thinking?

Comment: @Aqua The probabilistic argument you present in the question will not work. Take, for example, $k = 7$ and $A_1,A_2,A_3 = \{1,2,3,4\}$. Then $E(X)$ is strictly less than $3$ (you can compute it if you want), since you need to choose three distinct elements to achieve $\frac{3k}{7}$, which is the biggest $X$ can be.

In regards to your answer, everything looks right except for the statement "$|S| \le \frac{3k}{7}$", which doesn't make sense, since $|S|$ is a random variable. You need to show that the probability that $|S| \le \frac{3k}{7}$ *and* $X=n$ is positive.

Comment: Yes, I see. But in the later I among all $S$ choose the one with that $|S|\leq 3k/7$ and for this one try to prove $X=n$ is positive. @mathworker21 But it seems it does not work that way. I tried to imitate this solution to this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385805/graph-has-3n-vertices-and-every-two-has-common-neigbour-show-there-is-a-domin/3385904#3385904

Comment: @Aqua "and for this one try to prove $X=n$ is positive" no. you're still using probabilities. you can't cheat like that. in any event, I do like the idea of your answer, and I think the way to make it work is to instead choose $i$ to be in $S$ with probability $\frac{3k}{7}\frac{w(i)}{4n}$ instead of $\frac{3}{7}$, where $w(i) := \#\{1 \le j \le n : i \in A_j\}$. I also don't think you can imitate the solution to the problem you linked to, since there the union bound is fine, but here it is deadly.

Comment: Uhhh, that sounds very nice... Hope it will work :)

Comment: Dear mathworker, thank you for all your thoughts. I would only ask you to write all your comments as an answer. I can not reward you othervise. @mathworker21

Comment: @Aqua okay, no problem. I enjoy thinking about this stuff, and am happy you are trying to get really good at the probabilistic method. I'll type up my comments as an answer, but request that you either just upvote or accept my answer or give at most 50 bounty. Deal?

Comment: How can I give at most 50? If there will be a positivie answer it will get 500 and you 100

Comment: @Aqua you should tag me in your comments. unfortunately, I don't get a notification if you don't. I forgot there was a bounty on this question! Yea, if someone finds a probabilistic proof in the next 6 days, give them 600. Otherwise, I'm fine with the 100.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think a probabilistic argument would work. Take $m \ge 1, k = 4m, n = 3m$, and $A_1,A_2,A_3 = \{1,2,3,4\}, A_4,A_5,A_6 = \{5,6,7,8\}$, etc. Then we need at most $\frac{12}{7}m$ elements chosen, so on average we need a bit less than $2$ elements chosen from a batch of $3$. I don't see how a random choice will do this; the choices of elements from $A_2,A_3$ must depend on the choice of element from $A_1$. And once we start having these kinds of dependencies, the proof becomes much more combinatorial/deterministic and falls outside what any reasonable person would call a "probabilistic proof".

Note that the construction just mentioned rules out the probabilistic approach you outlined in the question. Indeed, $E(X)$ will be more than $\lfloor \frac{3k}{7} \rfloor$ ($m=1$ is easy to compute).

In regards to the approach you outlined in an answer, it nearly certainly is just as hard as the original approach. Indeed, it definitely will be true that $P(X=n) > 0$, since a valid choice of elements, one from each $E_i$, with size at most $\frac{3k}{7}$ could be the randomly chosen set $S$. The issue is that $P(X=n)$ will be exponentially small, and thus difficult to prove is nonzero. It will also be exponentially small even if we choose $X$ a bit more wisely, by, for example, choosing $i$ to be in $S$ with probability $\frac{3k}{7}\frac{\#\{1 \le j \le n : i \in A_j\}}{4n}$. I highly doubt there is any natural choice of probabilities that will yield $P(X=n)$ being not exponentially small.

Of course, there could be a completely different approach, that one would consider "probabilistic method" that does well with the construction mentioned at the beginning of my answer. However, I view that as unlikely, but I obviously cannot be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an atempt with no sucsess. Any idea how to fix it?

Suppose we take each element from $K$ at random and independently with probability $p={3\over 7}$. Let $S$ be a set of a choosen elements. Then $|S|\leq {3k\over 7}$.

Let $X$ be a number of all sets among $E_1,...,E_n$ that intersection with $S$ is nonempty. We are interested if $P(X=n)>0$ i.e.

$$P((S\cap E_1 \ne \emptyset) \cap (S\cap E_2 \ne \emptyset)\cap...\cap (S\cap E_n \ne \emptyset))>0$$

which is the same as $$1>P((S\cap E_1 = \emptyset) \cup (S\cap E_2 =\emptyset)\cup...\cup (S\cap E_n = \emptyset))$$

Say $E_i=\{a,b,c,d\}$. Now we have $$\color{red}{P(S\cap E_i=\emptyset)= P(a\notin S\cap b\notin S\cap c\notin S\cap d\notin S) = ({4\over 7})^4}$$

(**Is this correct?**)

So we have by the union bound $$P(\bigcup _{i=1}^n S\cap E_i)\leq n ({4\over 7})^4 \leq {3k\over 4}({4\over 7})^4 $$

which is not good since it goes over $1$ (if $k\geq 22$). Any help here?