# Graph has $3n$ vertices and every two has common neigbour. Show there is a dominant set with $n$ vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

A town has $3n$ citizens. Any two persons in the town have at least one common friend in this same town. Show that one can choose a group consisting of $n$ citizens such that every person of the remaining $2n$ citizens has at least one friend in this group of $n$.

I'm interested in an explanation of this probabilistic solution.

[image]
  [image]

I don't understand what is that random sample of $np$ vertices. Is $np$ an integer?!? And what is this replacement? And what is this union $S$ about?

Comment: The solution you provided solves a stronger problem -- it will find a much smaller dominating set than $n$ among the $3n$ citizens. There's also an easy non-probabilistic solution to find a dominating set of size $n$. How does your stated problem relate to the given solution?

Comment: Yeah I know about non probabilistic solution. However I 'm interested in explanation of this one or any alternative probailistic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often in proofs like this, there's an implicit "floor" or "ceiling" to make the relevant quantities into integers, which only slightly affects the final results. To make the solution a little clearer, let $k = \lceil np \rceil$ (the least integer $\geq np$).

By a random sample of $np$ vertices with replacement, they mean that $k$ vertices $x_1, \dots, x_k$ are chosen uniformly and independently at random (i.e. so $x_1, \dots, x_k$ are i.i.d. uniform vertices). You might imagine a process of picking the $k$ vertices randomly, one after another, putting the chosen vertex back after each choice (so it can be picked again). The union $S$ of the vertices is just the set containing the chosen vertices $x_1, \dots, x_k$.

The rest of the proof can be rephrased as:

> Note that $|S| \leq k \leq np+1$. Now the probability that a particular fixed vertex $v$ fails to have a neighbor in $S$ is strictly less than $(1 - p)^k$, because we need each of $k$ samples to miss the neighborhood of $v$. This is at most $(1-p)^{np} \leq e^{-np^2} \leq e^{-\log n} = n^{-1}$. Therefore a union bound over the $n$ choices of $v$ produces the result.

Comment: But why are they giving it back? I don't understand this. What is a point of it? And with what probability are they taking it out?

Comment: Each chosen vertex is picked uniformly, which means that for each vertex $u$ we have $x_i = u$ with probability $1/n$. The choices are "with replacement" just because this makes the calculations easier, since this means the points are picked independently -- this is a common practice in probability/combinatorics. For example, it's more work to get a bound like $(1-p)^k$ (or better) if the points are chosen without replacement.

Comment: Anyway can you think of an alternative (easier) probabilistic solution?

Comment: I will try, but these are all standard techniques for the probabilistic method, so I'm not sure I can cut it down much further

Comment: @Aqua - "Picking with replacement" is just standard language meaning the same thing can be picked again and again.   "Picking with replacement" is equivalent to rolling dice: Imagine for each of the $k$ choices, you roll an $n$-sided die, and you pick the node according to the die-roll.  Each die-roll is independent, so you may (or may not) have repeats among your $k$ rolls, which is why $|S|< k$ is possible.  The reason it's called "picking with replacement" is that _if_ this were an urn with $n$ balls and you draw one, you gotta put it back in (replace it!) before you make the next draw.